# lastInsertId returns 0

Tags: php, pdo

Actually, there is a lot of post about this. But even if I checked those, still couldn't find the problem.

**DBC class**

```
protected function connect(){

    $dns = "mysql:host=" . $this->server . ";dbname=" . $this->database;
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $this->username, $this->password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $pdo;
}
```

and insert function.

```
public function insert_row($created_at){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO empty_rows (created_at) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$created_at]);  
    $id = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();

    echo $id;
}
```

I think it should be return the last inserted Id but, it just returns 0. what am I missing here?

Comment: actually, inserrt is not failing. The row is inserted. I am checking the DB @Barmar

Comment: yes it has @Barmar

Comment: $this->connect() is not a singleton, pretty sure if you reconnect that value is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lastInsertId()` returns the ID that was inserted on the same connection. You get a new connection every time you call `$this->connect()`.

You need to save the result of `$this-connect()` so you use the same connection.

```
public function insert_row($created_at){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO empty_rows (created_at) VALUES (?)";
    $connect = $this->connect();
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$created_at]);  
    $id = $connect->lastInsertId();

    echo $id;
}
```

In general you'll slow your application down significantly if you keep creating new connections. I suggest you change the `connect()` method so it only connects the first time.

```
protected function connect(){
    if (!isset($this->pdo) {
        $dns = "mysql:host=" . $this->server . ";dbname=" . $this->database;
        $this->$pdo = new PDO($dns, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    return $this->$pdo;
}
```